# C# Get CPU and RAM from specific process (performance counters)

Tags: c#, process, cpu, monitor, performancecounter

I would like to retrieve the cpu and ram usage at that point for the foreground process (or a specific one).
Retrieving the window's title is not a problem and that part works. But the cpu display stays at 0% even when the active window is running at 70% cpu or more.

(int)pCPU.NextValue(); // <<<< keeps returning 0...

Note: I want to do it with a performance counter. I don't want to do it using the Process variable because that one might raise 'insufficient privilege errors'.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint ProcessId);

    public void GetActiveCPUAndRam(out string windowTitle, out int CPUUsagePerc, out int RAMUsage)
    {
        IntPtr hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        uint pid;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);

        Process activeProc = Process.GetProcessById((int) pid);

        #region Window Title

        const int nChars = 256;
        StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
        if (GetWindowText(hwnd, Buff, nChars) > 0)
            windowTitle = Buff.ToString();
        else
        {
            windowTitle = "";
            CPUUsagePerc = 0;
            RAMUsage = 0;
            return;
        }

        #endregion

        #region RAM/CPU
        PerformanceCounter pCPU = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", activeProc.ProcessName, true);
        pCPU.NextValue();
        CPUUsagePerc = (int)pCPU.NextValue(); // <<<<< problem here.

        RAMUsage = 0; // TODO:

        #endregion
    }
```

---

EDIT:
I tried the new solution:
But when I run a cpu stress test program that pushes the cpu usage to 100% (single core) . Then the solution below shows that the cpu usage of that process is like 300-400% of the total cpu... Obviously something is still wrong.

---

```
        private PerformanceCounter pCPU = null;
        private IntPtr PreviousProcHwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        private CounterSample PreviousCPUCounterSample = CounterSample.Empty;

        public void GetActiveCPUAndRam(out string windowTitle, out int CPUUsagePerc, out int RAMUsage)
{
        ...
        #region RAM/CPU

        if (PreviousProcHwnd != hwnd)
        {
            PreviousProcHwnd = hwnd;
            pCPU = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", activeProc.ProcessName,
                                                             true);
            PreviousCPUCounterSample = CounterSample.Empty;
        }

        CounterSample sample1 = pCPU.NextSample();
        CPUUsagePerc = (int)CounterSample.Calculate(PreviousCPUCounterSample, sample1);
        PreviousCPUCounterSample = sample1;
        RAMUsage = 0; // TODO:

        #endregion
}
```

Comment: have you seen http://openhardwaremonitor.org/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the value directly, use the calculated sample,

```
CounterSample sample1 = pCPU.NextSample();
float value = CounterSample.Calculate(sample1);
```

if your counter is a 'rate' type sample, then you will need to get two samples,

```
CounterSample sample1 = counter.NextSample();
Thread.Sleep(1000); // wait some time
CounterSample sample2 = counter.NextSample();
float value = CounterSample.Calculate(sample1, sample2);
```

Comment: The first sample doesn't work. The second sample gives me cpu usages that are different. I already have another counter measuring the total cpu load (which seems accurate) and that one displays like 50% for all processes while this one for a single process displays like 60%... That's not good. Also, is it not possible to do it without a thread.sleep but just do it in the same cycle without having to store the previous countersample from the same process or something? My application is framerate dependant and can not sleep like that. It might also crash if the process is closed during sleep().

Comment: I did some more tests on the second sample and the difference is ofcourse caused by the 1 second delay.. I feel so stupid.. But I was right that this will crash my program when the process that is being checked terminates within that 1 second (which is very likely).